# Load div value from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    function GetData(){
        return "three";
    }
</script>

<div>first</div>
<div>second</div>
<div></div>
```

How do you set the content for **just the third div** to come from the GetData() function, given that the divs might be nested in other divs and the whole pattern of divs repeated? Would every single div of every nested level need a unique id or class?

EDIT: It seems the simple answer is "Yes, every div, or group of divs, that is to modified must be uniquely identified. There is no simple way to associate a dynamic value to a specific div at the time of the div's definition". Thanks to the answers to-date which gave clues, but perhaps understandably didn't get the real question.

Comment: If you want to set the innerHTML of a specific element, I'd assign an ID to that specific element and utilize that.

Comment: i deleted my answer while i get some info from you... how are you planning to call the GetData function... you want all divs data, or just one div? its not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not require each div to be uniquely id'd or class'd use **Data Attributes**

Details here: [answered my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029425/dynamically-insert-value-into-multiple-rows-of-divs)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('div:nth-of-type(3)').innerHTML = GetData();
```

Basically you just have to find a right selector.

Answer (score 0):

> *How do you set the content for just the **third div***

**SOLUTION 1 :**

Add class/ID into your third div.

```js
const third = document.querySelector('.third'); // Select the class with the name is third.

const GetData = () => {
   return "three";
}

third.innerHTML = GetData(); // And set the new value
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

**SOLUTION 2 :**

This approach is more dynamic. No need to set class or something else :

```js
const div = document.querySelectorAll('div'); // Select the class with the name is third.

const GetData = () => {
   return "three";
}

div[div.length -1].innerHTML = GetData();
```

```html
<div><div>
<div><div>
<div><div>
```

I prefer the first solution !

Comment: Solution 1 (like other comments here) states the obvious: assign an id or class.
Your Solution 2 is interesting. I'll go away and think about it.
I was hoping for a method that could be embedded in or with the div definition that would only apply to that div.

Comment: If you have some other question post a comment and I will answer you :)